# BlobNotFound Error with FEAAS Component on Sitecore XM Cloud

Tags: xm-cloud

I am experiencing a **BlobNotFound** error when working with the FEAS component on Sitecore XM Cloud. The issue presents as an XML error message in the browser, stating, "The specified blob does not exist."

Attached are two screenshots detailing the error:

- The first shows the XML file error in the browser with a **BlobNotFound**
  code.

[image]

- The second is the browser console output, displaying a "Failed to
  load resource" message with a 404 status.

[image]

**Details:**

- **Sitecore XM Cloud Environment:** Production Environment
- **Component Name:** FEAAS
- **Error Messages:**

  ```
   - **BlobNotFound**

   - **The specified blob does not exist**.
  ```
- **RequestId:** 2e8bd925-e01e-0031-1bad-6f02f9000000
- **Time:** 2024-03-06T10:04:44.4159614Z

I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: have you raised a support ticket for this>